# How to refresh ViewModel data using Kotlin lazy loading coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to implement a SwipeToRefreshLayout in a weather app I'm building.  When the user swipes to refresh, the data in the ViewModel should be updated, and then the view should be updated accordingly.

Here is a snippet of my CurrentWeatherFragment:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
                .get(WeatherResponseViewModel::class.java)

        pullToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(this)

        bindUI()
    }

    override fun onRefresh() {
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
                .get(WeatherResponseViewModel::class.java)

        bindUI()
        pullToRefresh.isRefreshing = false
    }

    private fun bindUI() = launch {
        val currentWeather = viewModel.weather.await()
        currentWeather.observe(this@CurrentWeatherFragment, Observer {
            if (it == null) return@Observer

            loading_icon.visibility = View.GONE

            updateLocation("Raleigh")
            updateDateToToday()
            updateTemperatures(it.currently.temperature.roundToInt(),
                    it.currently.apparentTemperature.roundToInt(),
                    it.daily.data[0].temperatureMin.roundToInt(),
                    it.daily.data[0].temperatureMax.roundToInt())
            updateDescription(it.currently.summary)
            updateEnvironmentals((it.currently.humidity * 100).roundToInt(), it.currently.windSpeed.roundToInt())
            updateWeatherIcon(it.currently.icon)
            updateTempChart(it)
            updatePrecipChart(it)
        })
    }
```

my ViewModel:

```
class WeatherResponseViewModel (
        private val forecastRepository: ForecastRepository,
        unitProvider: UnitProvider
) : ViewModel() {

    private val unitSystem = unitProvider.getUnitSystem()

    val isMetric: Boolean
        get() = unitSystem == UnitSystem.METRIC

    val weather by lazyDeferred {
        forecastRepository.getWeather()
    }

}
```

and my lazyDeferred implementation:

```
fun <T> lazyDeferred(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T): Lazy<Deferred<T>> {
    return lazy {
        GlobalScope.async {
            block.invoke(this)
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, with this setup, the forecastRepository.getWeather() function in the ViewModel is called when the fragment is loaded either on app launch or when switching to it, but on the swipe to refresh, it isn't being called.  How can I get the weather variable in the ViewModel to update so that the view can observe the change?

Answer (score 8):

First, There are some wrong implementations about Coroutine and ViewModel in your code.

1. Do not re-instantiate ViewModel again in `onRefresh`.

   Instead, just make and call refresh method in your viewmodel when 
   SwipeRefreshLayout is pulled.
2. Do not use GlobalScope in your Application if you can.

   It can cause Work Leak and doesn't follow Structured concurrency rule.

   Instead, use `coroutineScope{}` block.
3. Do not use `LifecycleOwner` of `Fragment` for observing `LiveData` in fragment. It can generate duplicated observer for `LiveData`.

   Instead, use `viewLifecycleOwner` instance of fragment.

   This is becuase when the fragment is restored in back stack, the views of fragment is re-created, but fragment.

   If you match your observer lifecycle with views in fragment, `Ovserver`s won't remain after view is destoryed.

---

**Way to Refresh**

Don't use lazy block. It seems useless like `@Stanislav Bondar`'s answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  How would you remove the lazy call from the above code while still keeping the call asynchronous?

Comment: calling code **asynchronous** and using keyword **lazy** is absolutely not relevant to each other. **async** of coroutine function make code asynchronous itself. How about just remove lazy block from lazyDeffered. or just remove that and use coroutine directely

Comment: I did that originally and struggled, but I think I just got it to work with the lazy block removed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From Kotlin Delegated Properties:

> lazy properties: the value gets computed only upon first access;

Don't use `lazy` for mutable data

Comment: How would you remove that from the above code while still keeping the call asynchronous?

Comment: @cpgreen2 Replace  `Lazy<Deferred<T>>` with `Deferred<T>` and return `GlobalScope.async{..}.`